# How to view all cells value in a column by column header name using VBA in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Example of data:

[image]

VBA:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    'MsgBox "hello ti"
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Employee") ' Change this sheet to the one you are using if not the first sheet
        Set c = .Find("Phone", LookIn:=xlValues)
    
        For Each e In c
            MsgBox e
        Next
    
    End With
End Sub
```

I would like to display all phone numbers in the Phone column by targeting the column name "Phone".

Updated to(But only Displaying "Phone"):

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    
        Set c = .Find("Phone", LookIn:=xlValues)
        
        For Each e In c
              MsgBox e
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: What does you code do? How do the results differ from what you want?

Comment: It's giving me (Run-time error’9′)

Comment: Which line is throwing the error? BTW, when using VBA, it is **always** a good idea to put Option Explicit at the top of the module and declare all your variables with Dim statements.

Comment: @NicholasHunter I have updated the code has no errors but its only displaying "Phone".

Comment: `Find` returns a `Range` object of the first found cell. You should be able to look at that `Range` object and get the column index; you can then use that column index to get back the values from the `UsedRange` for the corresponding column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Showing Column Contents in a Message Box

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Employee")
        Dim fCell As Range
        Set fCell = .UsedRange.Find("Phone", , xlFormulas, xlWhole)
        Dim lCell As Range
        Set lCell = .Cells(.Rows.Count, fCell.Column).End(xlUp)
        Dim rg As Range
        Set rg = .Range(fCell, lCell)
    End With
    
    MsgBox Join(Application.Transpose(rg.Value), vbLf)

End Sub
```